# Transformation from axis to absolute figure coordinates using display coordinates does not work in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, transformation

I need to plot point markers at the edge along the y-axes in Matplotlib. I want the location of the markers in x-direction to be constant (independent of the size of the axes) while y-direction should be in data coordinates. I've tried to create blended transformation according to [Transformations tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations) but it did not work according to my expectations. Can anyone explain where I'm making a mistake? And how to fix it?

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.__version__) # 3.3.1

import matplotlib.transforms as transforms
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 3.5))
ax.set_xlim((0,2))
ax.set_ylim((0,2))
ax.plot([0,2], [0,2])
ax.grid(True)
fig.set_facecolor('lightgray')
point = [1,0]

# Ok, let's use the y-axis transform to plot in axis coordinates in the x-direction
t_yaxis = ax.get_yaxis_transform()
ax.scatter([1, 1.1], [2, 2], transform=t_yaxis, clip_on=False, label='p1')
# This works but the distance between points depends on the size of the axes. 
# We want to set it in absolute units.

# Here we create blended transformation which actually works exactly the same as the previous one.
t_own_yaxis = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transAxes, ax.transData)
ax.scatter([1, 1.1], [1.5, 1.5], transform=t_own_yaxis, clip_on=False, label='p2')

# Let's try to blend physical coordinates of the figure in x-direction 
# with data coordinates in y-direction.
t_blended = transforms.blended_transform_factory(fig.dpi_scale_trans, ax.transData)
ax.scatter([1, 1.1], [1, 1], transform=t_blended, clip_on=False, label='p3')
# This works for distance between points but we want to offset the points at the edge of the axes
# asi in previous cases.

# Let's calculate the location of the edge and plot using that.
t_yaxis2blended = t_yaxis + t_blended.inverted()
p4 = t_yaxis2blended.transform([1, 0.5])
print(p4)
ax.scatter([p4[0], p4[0]+0.1], [0.5, 0.5], transform=t_blended, clip_on=False, label='p4')
# Why the left 'p4' point is not at the edge?

plt.legend()
```

[image]

[Edit] The blue, orange and green dots are where I expected them. I expected the left red dot at [2.0, 0.5].

Interestingly, if I use interactive backend `%matplotlib notebook` for rendering of the plots the result is as expected:

[image]

[Edit] The reason I need this is to annotate dendrograms like this:
[image]

Comment: The orange and blue dots are where I expected them to be based on the transforms you used.  Where did you *want* them to be?

Comment: I expected the left red dot at [2.0, 0.5].

Comment: In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/27892824/603323  it is suggested to call `plt.draw()`. I have tested that. There is also a suggestion to "link things through figure coordinates". This seems interesting but I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: EDIT: oops I'm sorry I didn't see your edit.

Comment: Your green dots are 1 inch to the right of the left edge of the figure.  Your red dots are 1 inch to the right of the left edge of the axes.  I think its all consistent?

Comment: I expected the location of the red dots (p4) to be transformed like follows: 1.0 in axes coordinates is exactly the right edge of axes -> x0 in display coords -> x1 in absolute fig coords (`dpi_scale_trans.inverted()`). x1 is then plotted using absolute fig coords, therefore it should be at the right edge.

Comment: OK, fair enough.  Thats correct so long as you don;t change the figure size.  The issue if you use `%matplotlib inline` is it resizes the figure for you by calling `fig.savefig('repr.png', bbox_inches='tight')`.  The moral of the story is don't use `dpi_scale_trans` unless you really want something in absolute inches, regardless of figure size.

Comment: Thanks, this explains the problem. But what can I do when I *want* to specify the horizontal distance between points in absolute units, i.e. they don't change when I change the horizontal size of the axes?

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear what you want.  Just consider the x position: do you want one dot in data space, and the second dot a fixed number of inches away?

Comment: It *sounds* like you want a `ScaledTranslation`: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#plotting-in-physical-coordinates

Comment: @JodyKlymak I've edited the question to make my intent more clear. I just want to plot points at the right edge of the axes with their horizontal spacing independent of the size of the fig/axes. Maybe `ScaledTranslation` would be another way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use axes scale and calculate the absolute distance between points from axes size:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 3.5))
ax.set_xlim((0,2))
ax.set_ylim((0,2))
ax.plot([0,2], [0,2])
ax.grid(True)
fig.set_facecolor('lightgray')

t_yaxis = ax.get_yaxis_transform()
ax.scatter([1, 1.1], [2, 2], transform=t_yaxis, clip_on=False, label='p1')

bbox = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
shift = 0.1 / bbox.width
ax.scatter([1, 1 + shift], [0, 0], transform=t_yaxis, clip_on=False, label='p5')

plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to offset something, you can use a `ScaledTransform`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 3.5))
ax.set_xlim((0,2))
ax.set_ylim((0,2))
ax.plot([0,2], [0,2])

t_yaxis = ax.get_yaxis_transform()
ax.scatter([1], [2], transform=t_yaxis, clip_on=False, label='p1')

# offset -0.25 inch horizontally
trans = t_yaxis + transforms.ScaledTranslation(-0.25, 0, fig.dpi_scale_trans)
ax.scatter([1], [2], transform=trans, clip_on=False, label='p1')

plt.show()
```

[image]

This will make the second (orange) point always offset from the blue by -0.25 inches, regardless of window resizing (note the figure above has been resized manually)

More details at https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#plotting-in-physical-coordinates